# Multiple layout events in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

Is it possible to attach multiple layout events to a PdfPCell?

I read that there's a method for setting a cell event: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPCell.html#setCellEvent(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCellEvent)

I'm not sure if it's possible to set **multiple** events. I would like to seperate different cell options in seperate events based on my business logic. Sometimes I want to draw an ellipse in it, sometimes a square (or anything else).It would be nice if I could simply attach the events that I need.

Thanks for any response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add multiple cell events to a cell. This is the Java code of the `setCellEvent()` method:

```
public void setCellEvent(PdfPCellEvent cellEvent) {
    if (cellEvent == null) {
        this.cellEvent = null;
    } else if (this.cellEvent == null) {
        this.cellEvent = cellEvent;
    } else if (this.cellEvent instanceof PdfPCellEventForwarder) {
        ((PdfPCellEventForwarder) this.cellEvent).addCellEvent(cellEvent);
    } else {
        PdfPCellEventForwarder forward = new PdfPCellEventForwarder();
        forward.addCellEvent(this.cellEvent);
        forward.addCellEvent(cellEvent);
        this.cellEvent = forward;
    }
}
```

If you pass `null`, then all existing events are removed from the cell. If no cell event was present, a new cell event is added. If there is already a cell event present, a [`PdfPCellEventForwarder`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/events/PdfPCellEventForwarder.html) is created. This is a class that stores different cell events and that eventually will execute all these events one by one.

**Update:**

iTextSharp (C#) is kept in sync with iText (Java), so this functionality also works for iTextSharp. I have just checked the iTextSharp code and I've found this:

```
virtual public IPdfPCellEvent CellEvent {
    get {
        return this.cellEvent;
    }
    set {
        if (value == null) this.cellEvent = null;
        else if (this.cellEvent == null) this.cellEvent = value;
        else if (this.cellEvent is PdfPCellEventForwarder) ((PdfPCellEventForwarder)this.cellEvent).AddCellEvent(value);
        else {
            PdfPCellEventForwarder forward = new PdfPCellEventForwarder();
            forward.AddCellEvent(this.cellEvent);
            forward.AddCellEvent(value);
            this.cellEvent = forward;
        }
    }
}
```

So there is no need to create your own `PdfPCellEventForwarder` (although you may do so if you want to), iTextSharp will take care of creating a `PdfPCellEventForwarder` in your place if you add multiple events to a `PdfPCell`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's too bad that this method isn't available in the .NET version of iText :-(

Comment: I found the answer thanks to your response. The PdfPCellEventForwarder class is publicly available in iTextSharp. An instance of this can be set to the CellEvent property of a PdfPCell. On the instance, one can call the AddCellEvent method.
If you rewrite your answer a bit, I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I wasen't aware that I could just keep using the 'setter' of the CellEvent property.